# Ionic3 [style.backgroundImage]-binding not updating UI on iOS only

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've run in to this problem where I'm trying to display a picture chosen from the devices photo-gallery in two places in the form of data URLs (`data:image/jpeg;base64,...`).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pic-img-wrapper" [style.backgroundImage]="imgSrc | safeStyleUrl" float-right (click)="toggleImgs()" tappable>
</div>
```

and

```
<div *ngFor="let img of imgSrcs; let i = index"  [style.backgroundImage]="img | safeStyleUrl">
    <span (click)="removeImage(i)" tappable>X</span>
</div>
```

I use a `pipe` to sanitize the data URLs:

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'safeStyleUrl'
})
export class SafeStyleUrlPipe{
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

    transform(url:string){
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url(' + url + ')');
    }
}
```

I have wrapped the assignment of the data URLs to `imgSrc` and `imgSrcs` in `zone.run()`:

```
private handleNewPicture(imageData:any):void{
    if(this.imgSrcs.length < 3){
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.imgSrcs.push(imageData);
            this.imgSrc = imageData;
            this.emitChange();
        });
    }
}
```

The images display correctly on Android device but not on iOS device.
When debugging my iOS device I can see that the data URL is passed to the `pipe`. Also the `*ngFor` in the second `HTML`-snippet creates the correct amount of elements, but no background image.
Uploading the images to my Firebase Storage works.